# Antlr any character untill string

Tags: antlr4

I want a rule with ANTLR that parse any character as number, string special('@ space) etc until the word FOOTER(not included)

The text that I want parse is like this

```
HEADER:
Date Id other stuff.
CONTENT 
... Any character
FOOTER
Other stuff
END
```

I try with this code:
In the lexer.

```
HEADER:  'HEADER';
CONTENT: 'CONTENT';
FOOTER:  'FOOTER';
END:     'END';
ANY_CHARACTER: .* ~[FOOTER \r\n];
```

In the parser.

```
HEADER ... The other rules
CONTENT ANY_CHARACTER 
FOOTER ...
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be a lexer rule:

```
TRAILING_CONTENT: 'FOOTER' .*? 'END';
```

You would, then (of course), need to strip the `CONTENT` and `END` parts from your token. This works because ANTLR tokenization will prefer the lexer rule that matches the longest stream of input characters (it *does* assume that it wouldn't be valid anywhere else in you input though, as it would gather all of that into a single token.

NOTE: This assumes that your goal is to parse an input file where anything at all will occur between `CONTENT` and `FOOTER` (with the exception of `END`), and that you want to treat it all as a single token and don't need to "parse" it.  (Though that could be done with another grammar for the content.)

Comment: Yes this is the goal. But when I put TRAILING_CONTENT  in the lexer, the parser when try to look for TRAILING_CONTENT say  "Missing TRAILING_CONTENT"

Comment: What says  "Missing TRAILING_CONTENT" ?   Is it a parse error? an error when you try to run antlr code generation?  You'll need to share more information to troubleshoot that.  (maybe your grammar and the sample input that fails, if it's an error from attempting to parse.)

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution myself.

```
.*? (FOOTER \r\n)
```

with .* we accept all characters untill the end of file.

with *?* we add the rule untill the next rule is true, so untill we find

```
(FOOTER \r\n)
```

Comment: This will result in a separate token for each character in your `.*?` part of the rule.  If that doesn't matter to you, then small matter (and you can use `getText(startToke start, Token stop)` to retrieve all that text).  But, depending upon your content you will have a LOT of tokens.

Comment: yes you're right, have you a better solution?

Comment: It'll actually match all the tokens non-greedily, so any lexer rules you have (other than `FOOTER`) will appear in that set of tokens (so not all will be individual characters.

Comment: Have you an example? the big problem with my solution is that the parser now is slower than before

Comment: BTW, `ANY_CHARACTER: .* ~[FOOTER \r\n];` isn't doing what you think it is.  the `[` and `]` contain a set of individual characters, so `ANY_CHARACTER` will produce a token for any characters other than `F`, `O`, `T`,`E`,`R`, ` `,`\r, or `\n` (not all characters up until the string `"FOOTER \r\n"`. (Assuming that rule remained in your solution)